# Use bash variables in subsequent bash command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a bash script which shows me all tcp connections which are important for me. For that I use `netstat -atp`. It looks like this:

```
num_haproxy_443_established=$(netstat -atp | grep ESTABLISHED | grep :https | grep haproxy | wc -l)
printf "\n show ESTABLISHED connections port 443 \n"
printf " %s" $num_haproxy_443_established
```

In the bash script I have some of these calls and now I would like to optimize it and call `netstat -atp` only once and reuse the results. I tried:

```
netstat_res=$(netstat -atp)

num_haproxy_443_timewait=$("$netstat_res" | grep TIME_WAIT | grep :https | grep haproxy | wc -l)
printf " %s" $num_haproxy_443_timewait
```

After executing the script I always get `0: command not found` as error message. How can I use a variable inside $(...) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Because I don't want to create a file every time it runs.

Comment: Fair enough, but you not piping the contents of `netstat_res` to `grep` by `$(echo "$netstat_res" | grep TIME_WAIT | grep :https | grep haproxy | wc -l)`

Comment: If you set your variable to `netstat_res="netstat -atp"` it would work but then you'd call netstat every time (not sure why you would want to re-use its results anyway)

Comment: Sometimes I want to monitor the load on a loadbalancer. Therefore I would run this script every second for about 30 seconds or so. When there are 1000 or more connections I don't want to run netstat 8 times or more but only once.

Comment: I think an `awk` with `print` is probably going to be a cleaner solution or answer. Similar to what @anubhava proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like `A="foo"` then `$("$A")` will be resolved to call the program `foo` in the subshell.

So you just have to echo the content of the variable and then grep from it:

```
num_haproxy_443_timewait=$(echo "$netstat_res" | grep TIME_WAIT ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell array to store your `netstat` command:

```
# your netstat command
netstat_res=(netstat -atp)

# then execute it as
num_haproxy_443_timewait=$("${netstat_res[@]}" |
awk '/TIME_WAIT/ && /:TIME_WAIT/ && /haproxy/{++n} END{print n}')

echo $num_haproxy_443_timewait
```

Also note how you can avoid multiple `grep` calls by a single `awk` call.

**Related BASH FAQ**: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: no arrays needed for this... the newlines will be preserved in the bash variable.. only `echo "$netstat_res"` is needed

Comment: ok I see your point but caching `netstat` results and reusing might give wrong results depending upon life of the cache.

Comment: To make `netstat` run faster I suggest using `netstat -atnp`

Answer (score 0):

At your case, $netstat_res is the result but not the COMMAND, if you want to save the result and use it not only once, save the result to the file is the better way, such as:

```
    netstat -atp > /tmp/netstat_status.txt
    num_haproxy_443_timewait=$(cat /tmp/netstat_status.txt | grep TIME_WAIT | grep :https | grep haproxy | wc -l)
    printf " %s" $num_haproxy_443_timewait
```

Comment: Yes, $netstat_res is the result. I want to use the result as input for the next commands like grep. I don't want to save the result as a file because that's unnecessary disk usage.

Comment: @Hamburml Oh I see, but "echo $netstat_res" will lose the "\n" separtor, how to fix it?

Comment: But it works with echo, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44648712/3069477